# Tabbing on a Modal doesn't focus on the further elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a focus trap on a modal. I followed this wonderful [tutorial](https://medium.com/@seif_ghezala/how-to-create-an-accessible-react-modal-5b87e6a27503). But it doesn't work when I have more than 2 focusable elements. It is not iterating. And I couldn't come up with a good idea for the iteration. As you can also experiment and try from the codesandbox, wen I console.log(focusableModalElements) I can see the array of elements.

https://codesandbox.io/s/tabbing-on-a-modal-l412c?file=/src/Modal/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the conditions in the checks and it will make it

```
const isAmongElements = (elements, elm) => {
    for (let element of elements) {
      if (element === elm) return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  const modalRef = createRef();
  const handleTabKey = (e) => {
    const focusableModalElements = modalRef.current.querySelectorAll(
      'a[href], button, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], select'
    );
    console.log("focusableElements", focusableModalElements); // all here
    const firstElement = focusableModalElements[0];
    const lastElement =
      focusableModalElements[focusableModalElements.length - 1];

    if (
      !e.shiftKey &&
      (!isAmongElements(focusableModalElements, document.activeElement) ||
        document.activeElement === lastElement)
    ) {
      firstElement.focus();
      return e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (
      e.shiftKey &&
      (!isAmongElements(focusableModalElements, document.activeElement) ||
        document.activeElement === firstElement)
    ) {
      lastElement.focus();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
```

Comment: it goes to the next one but somehow it hasn't trapped the focus on the modal any more. The sandbox I created has only one element on the html so we don't feel it but it is like that

Comment: The esc touch don't work or why do you feel so ?

Comment: Just one focusable element or one element and the two close buttons ?

Comment: normally you would have many other elements on the page (container page) and the aim is trapping the focus on the modal when it is open and then move to the next one when tab is pressed and move back to the previous one when shift+tab is pressed. with your approach focus is not on the modal. imagine pressing 30 times tab so u can have the focus on the modal. not a good approach Edited the codsandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tabbing-on-a-modal-l412c?file=/src/Modal/index.js

Comment: Yes, I see. I added a function to check if the focus is inside the modal.

Comment: care to share the function? :) I can't see your edits on codesandbox.